# echo fails to write to open file descriptor

Tags: shell, pipe, posix

I have a pipe opened with `pipe()` in my C program and the write end of the pipe is passed through to a shell script using an environment variable so that when the script is run I can receive output from the shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh

update() {
    f="${1}"

    [ -z "${f}" ] || [ -z "${PIPE}" ] && return

    read -r fd <<-EOF
            ${PIPE}
            EOF

    echo "${f}" >&"${fd}"
}

update scripts
```

The expected output is to write `scripts` to the file descriptor set by `PIPE`. `PIPE` is set correctly and I can verify that by echoing it to a temporary file. I can also see that the pipe is open by echoing `lsof` of the current process to a file.

When running it with a known pipe (0, 1, or 2) it behaves normally but with any other single digit number (in this case 3) it will output `./test.sh: line 21: 1: Bad file descriptor` obviously since the pipe is not open. But I get a different error with an open pipe that is a two digit number. 10 and 11 work (I think it might be interpreting them as stdout and stdin) but 12 and up produce this message: `./test.sh: line 21: echo: write error: Bad file descriptor` and given that I cannot reliably predict the output of pipe() having a static number isn't a great solution as often it will produce two digit numbers.

Any ideas on solving this? I'm new at shell scripts so I'm not quite sure what the issue is.

Comment: Could we see a working [mcve], please?  I don't see a line 21 in your script.  I do see `x.sh: line 16: syntax error: unexpected end of file`, however. How can we ourselves verify that $PIPE is set properly? How can we ourselves verify that the redirection is working? Is this bash or dash or ash or what?

Comment: @pilcrow Line 21 would be the final echo that writes out to ${fd}. You can try setting $PIPE using a simple `export PIPE="num" and the problem only effects dash. I believe I've figured out the problem though. The file descriptor created by pipe() would usually be a two digit number which isn't supported by the POSIX standard.